# Is it possible to prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(kx)}{k^a}\geq 0$ for $a\geq 1$ and $x\in [0,\pi]$?

Tags: fourier-series, trigonometric-series, bernoulli-polynomials

I was trying to prove that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(kx)}{k^a}\geq 0,$$

for $0\leq x\leq \pi$, and $a\geq1$.

For $a$ being an odd integer, this is not really a problem, as the sums may then be expressed using Bernoulli polynomials. However, it seems that the assumption is true for all (real) values of $a$, not just integers, so I tried to split the sums and estimate the remainders, but unfortunately to no avail.

Does anyone have an idea on how to tackle this problem?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Do you mean $k^a$?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, corrected it, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can assume that $x\neq 0$. Then your sum is
$$
\Im \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{e^{ixk} }}{{k^a }}}  = \Im \operatorname{Li}_a (e^{ix} ) = \frac{1}{{\Gamma (a)}}\Im \int_0^{ + \infty } \!\!\frac{{t^{a - 1} }}{{e^{t - ix}  - 1}}dt = \frac{\sin x}{{\Gamma (a)}}\int_0^{ + \infty } \!\!\frac{{t^{a - 1} e^t }}{{e^{2t}  - 2e^t \cos x + 1}}dt ,
$$
which has the desired property since $
e^{2t}  - 2e^t \cos x + 1 > e^{2t}  - 2e^t  + 1 = (e^t  - 1)^2  > 0$ for $t>0$. Here $\operatorname{Li}_a$ denotes the polylogarithm, see http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.12.ii.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will go through this and check if I understand everything

Comment: I know the integral representation of the polylogarithm. I just can't see, how you made the last step, i.e. getting the sine out of the integral again and turning it thereby in a purely real integral, I've got to go through that.

Comment: I used the fact that $$
\frac{1}{{e^{t - ix}  - 1}} = \frac{{e^t \cos x - 1}}{{e^{2t}  - 2e^t \cos x + 1}} + i\frac{{e^t \sin x}}{{e^{2t}  - 2e^t \cos x + 1}}.
$$

Comment: Alright, now I got it! Thank you ever so much!

Comment: Taking a second look at your proof, I think my statement may even be made "stronger" in the sense that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(kx)}{k^a}> 0$ on the open interval $0<x<\pi$.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.